# Next.js search/filtering form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to React and Next.js and during learning this libraries I encountered this difficulty.

I am trying to make a filterable table with some fetched data.

Data from API is loaded on server side through `getInitialProps()` method.

```js
static async getInitialProps(context) {

        const elements = await getElements()

        return {
            elements: elements,
        }
}
```

Then I am rendering Bootstrap table with data and filtering form. Simplified example:

```js
render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Form>
                   <FilterInput name="name"></FilterInput>
                   <FilterInput name="surnname"></FilterInput>
                   <SearchButton></SearchButton>
               </Form>
               <table>
                   <tr>
                     <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Surname</th>
                   </tr>
                   {this.props.elements.map((element, index) => (
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           {element.name}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           {element.surname}
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                   )}
               </table>
            <div>
        )
}
```

My first idea was to handle search form submit event, get search inputs values and redirect user to the page with url like this:
`http://localhost:3000/elements?name=enetered_name&surname=enetered_surname`

Then retrieve query string params from `context` variable in `getInitialProps`, pass this params to `getElements` method and fetch it again from API but now with additional filters. But this solution worked only on first page reload (from server).

My guts are telling me that this is not right solution and I am overcomplicating this. I dont want working code from You. I only need tips and guide how to work this out.